# How do we find vi-like key bindings in Intel python?

Tags: linux, intel, intel-oneapi, intel-python

I have set up the system default python to accept the vi-like key bindings (e.g. `k` for previous line in the history) by writing the following line in `~/.inputrc

```
set editing-mode vi
```

The system's built-in Python REPL uses the 'readline' library, which can read configuration files. However, it doesn't appear that this file is having any impact on Intel Python.                                                                                                How can I use the vi-like key bindings in the REPL (the interactive command line interpreter) of Intel Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use vi-like key bindings in Intel Python, you need to install gnureadline package since Intel Python uses GPL code and that license is not compatible with the Intel MKL library.

```
pip install gnureadline
```

Intel Python will respect the `~/.inputrc` file containing the "`set editing-mode vi`" line.